# JSP servlets and Threads or Java Applet

Tags: java, multithreading, jsp, servlets, applet

Basically there is a php based portal. I was asked to change one of the pages that is doing backward validation on xml files to java. My question is:

1. Should I use Java Applet or JSP servlets?
2. What are pros and cons of each one?
3. A lot of people will use it at same time. Does it mean that with JSP I will have do   something with multi-threading?

NOTE that I am not reading or saving anything to server database etc. It is just all about compering two xml files and do it as fast as it is possible.

Comment: Why not keep it in PHP? Anyway, use JSP and Servlets over Applets since you need to sign the latter.

Comment: Based on what other users will advice me I will write a proposal and not me but someone else will decide. I was asked to do pros and cons of that idea. Why not php? New release of a page. Btw server sometimes just choke on big files and is being timed out there are a lot of problems with recent release so we want to make it as efficient as it is possible asap.

Comment: The main difference is that an Applet runs in the browser on the user's machine while a Servlet runs on the server.

Comment: Running Java on the server is safe.  Running Java in the browser via a browser plugin is a major security problem.  Anyone who knows much about computers will avoid your site like the plague if you use applets since that means they have to run the Java browser plugin.

Comment: And users who have no clue how to install Java will avoid your site like the plague if you use Applets too.  JSP/Servlets is more like PHP than Applets anyway since they all run serverside.  Applets are like Flash but much much less popular.

Comment: Security is not a problem as everything in running in priv network. My question is if I will have to spawn a new thread for every connected user. I give u example:
1) Server is running waiting for users
2) Users connects(do I spawn new thread to handle this user or is it more like php I dont do it?)
3) User uploads two files server do validation
4) Server output validation report

Comment: Your servlets or JSPs will typically run in a JavaEE Web Container. The container manages a thread pool and takes care of all the threading details. Just make sure, your code is thread safe.